# Add contents of arraylist to string array

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, arrays, arraylist

In for each loop i am adding the contents into ArrayList. Now i need to add (or copy/move) the contents of arraylist into string array.

By string array i mean string[].

let me know if more info required.

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcyyh2hb.aspx):

```
string[] array = (string[])list.ToArray(typeof(string));
```

I would recommend you use `List<string>` though, as that's more type safe:

```
List<string> list = ...
string[] array = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. I used your code such as      string[] strTemp = (string[])PDFSelectedList.ToArray(typeof(string));       It threws an error "At least one element in the source array could not be cast down to the destination array type."

Comment: here PDFSelectedList is an ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Use the toArray() method:

```
ArrayList alist = ...;

String []strArray = new String[alist.size()];
alist.toArray(strArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ToArray, which others have posted, but if you want to do some checking on the original list, or modify specific items as they're entered, you can also use something like this:

```
var myStringArray = new string[ArrayList.Count];
int i = 0;
foreach(var item in ArrayList)
{
 myStringArray[i] = item;
 i++;
}
```